# nmtui-connection change my MAC address

Tags: networkmanager

When I use `nmtui-connect` connect to a Wifi connection, my Wifi connection is changed automatically.
I need to put my MAC address into my modem as permit list, but after running `nmtui-connect` my mac will be changed.

How can I run `nmtui-connect` without any changing my mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the following rule into `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```